# Changing the status of a user by the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Okay, I'm going to explain this in the best way I can, and I hope you can understand what I'm asking.

I have created a mongo db collection named "users," and in that collection there are two things: 1) my profile, 2) my friends profile.

As for that, 1) has "user: jrose" and my friends 2) user: bgott

I have a on_call page working, but I want to be able to change the status by a click of a button. For example, I am primary at the moment, and I want to switch my friend to secondary. But there is a log in on the website, and the site recognizes that person, so my friend would have to log into his account for the website to recognize him and he would be able to take over my primary status by clicking a button.

```
 app.post("/web/on_call", function(req, res) {
            var position = req.query.position;
            console.log("asdf" + req.query.position)
            app.models.call_lists.findOne( { name: req.query.list }).lean().exec(function (err, call_list) {

                            res.redirect('/web/status');
            });
    });
```

After he clicks the button, I want it to direct back to the /web/status page.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1><%=call_list.name%></h1>
<% for (j=0;j<call_list.list.length;j++) { %>
<% if(position == call_list.list[j].position){ %>
                     <%= call_list.list[j].user %> was on call
                     <form method="post"> <button type="submit">I want to be on call.  </button> </form>
</form>
<% } %>
<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Comment: Wow! do you really need a POST method for just a submit button?

Comment: so a simple redirection? you can do redirect on both client and server side.